# Why can't I find memory pool size within Websphere Application Server metrics?

Tags: memory, websphere, jmx, metrics

I am trying to put together a script to monitor metrics from Websphere. Working with a list of PMIs. Everything is going great, but I can't figure out a couple of things:
- memory pool size
- busy threads
- connection and request counts

I've done the same exercise for Tomcat and was able to get MBean metrics for all of the above. But, if I understand it correctly, Websphere has its own flavor of MBeans, so it does not translate.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

Start with this page [PMI data organization](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprf_dataorg.html?lang=en). You will find all metrics WebSphere provides. There are metrics for JVM, DataSource and Thread pools also.

See also:

- [JDBC connection pool counters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter2.html?lang=en)
- [Java virtual machine counters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter4.html?lang=en)
- [Thread pool counters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter9.html?lang=en)
- [Developing your own monitoring applications](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_pmi.html?lang=en)
- [Using the JMX interface to develop your own monitoring application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_pmijmx.html?lang=en)